# How to indentify a fingerprint

Tags: fingerprint, biometrics

I am working with a Safran Morpho 1300 E3 biometric fingerprint scanner.From its response text i am getting three values:Base64ISOTemplate,Base64RAWIMage and Base64BMPIMage.How can I identify a fingerprint from these three values?

Comment: What's method do you call to obtain this result ? What're methods available ?

Comment: The method is CallFingerAPI().   Another method named CompareTemplates() is also available.

Comment: Can you code of these two methods here ?